# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefine

Tags: javascript

I get the error once I enter details in the description and value section and hit the green arrow. Can anyone have a look what is going wrong at my end!
Please refer to the below link
https://jsfiddle.net/5wdb0eco/

Error message:

```
app.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.addListItem (app.js:86)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ctrlAddItem (app.js:124)
```

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/5wdb0eco/

Comment: `if(type === 'inc') { ... } else if(type === 'exp') { ... }`... but what if neither is true? Then `html` remains undefined.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I see...Valid ! aaghhh

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol think I got it!!!! the type is undefined currently(that should have been first thing I should have checked)... Once I fix it, it will only bring back "inc" or "exp".. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code below:

```
        var ctrlAddItem = function(){
            var input, newItem;
            //  1. GET THE FIELD INPUT DATA
            input = UIController.getInput();
            console.log(input.type)
            //console.log(input);
            //  2. ADD THE ITEM TO THE BUDGET CONTROLLER
            newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);
            console.log(newItem)
            //  3. ADD THE ITEM TO THE UI
            UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, newItem.type);

            //  4. CALCULATE BUDGET
            //  5. DISPLAY THE BUDGET ON THE UI
        };
```

I added the console.log but your `newItem` from `budgetCtrl.addItem` does not return an object with `type` property attached to it.  Because of that passing it in to the `UICtrl.addListItem` function results in `undefined`

Your `newItem` that you are returning is one of the following:

```
        var Expense = function(id, description, value){
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
            this.value = value;
        };
        var Income = function(id, description, value){
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
            this.value = value;
        };
```

i.e. `new Expense` or `new Income` inside your `addListItem`

Change your expense and income functions to pass in a parameter of `type` and then in the `addItem` function pass the `type` into the instance as shown below:

```
                if(type === 'exp'){
                    newItem = new Expense(type, ID, des, val);
                }
                else if(type === 'inc') {
                    newItem = new Income(type, ID, des, val);
                }
```